# Surprising challenge generating comprehensive list

Tags: python, list, set, unique

I am facing a surprising challenge with Python.

I am a Physicist generating a series of simulations of layers at an optical interface. The details of the simulations are not specifically important but what is crucial is that I generate all possible cases are generated - different materials within a range of thicknesses and layer orders.

I have been writing code to generate a comprehensive and unique list but I am staggered at how long it takes to compute even relatively simple systems! Surely Python and a reasonable computer should handle this without excessive stress. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations_with_replacement

def join_adjacent_repeated_materials(potential_structure):
    """
    Self-explanitory...
    """
    #print potential_structure

    new_layers = [] # List to hold re-cast structure
    for layer in potential_structure:
        if len(new_layers) > 0: # if not the first item in the list of layers
            last_layer=new_layers[-1] # last element of existing layer list
            if layer[0] == last_layer[0]: # true is the two layers are the same material
                combined_layer = (layer[0], layer[1] + last_layer[1])
                new_layers[len(new_layers)-1] = combined_layer
            else: # adjcent layers are different material so no comibantion is possible
                new_layers.append(layer)
        else: # for the first layer
            new_layers.append(layer)

    return tuple(new_layers)

def calculate_unique_structure_lengths(thicknesses, materials, maximum_number_of_layers,\
                                       maximum_individual_layer_thicknesses, \
                                       maximum_total_material_thicknesses):
    """
    Create a set on all possible multilayer combinations.

    thicknesses : if this contains '0' the total number of layers will vary
                  from 0 to maximum_number_of_layers, otherwise, the
                  number total number layers will always be maximum_number_of_layers
                  e.g. arange(0 , 100, 5)

    materials : list of materials used
                e.g. ['Metal', 'Dielectric']

    maximum_number_of_layers : pretty self-explanitory...
                               e.g. 5

    maximum_individual_layer_thicknesses : filters the created the multilayer structures
                                           preventing the inclusion layers that are too thick
                                           - this is important after the joining of
                                           adjacent materials
                                           e.g. (('Metal',30),('Dielectric',20))

    maximum_total_material_thicknesses : similar to the above but filters structures where the total
                                         amount of a particular material is exceeded
                                         e.g. (('Metal',50),('Dielectric',100))


    """
    # generate all possible thickness combinations and material combinations
    all_possible_thickness_sets = set(permutations(combinations_with_replacement(thicknesses, maximum_number_of_layers)))
    all_possible_layer_material_orders = set(permutations(combinations_with_replacement(materials, maximum_number_of_layers)))


    first_set = set() # Create set object (list of unique elements, no repeats)
    for layer_material_order in all_possible_layer_material_orders:
        for layer_thickness_set in all_possible_thickness_sets:
            potential_structure = [] # list to hold this structure
            for layer, thickness in zip(layer_material_order[0], layer_thickness_set[0]): # combine the layer thickness with its material
                if thickness != 0: # layers of zero thickness are not added to potential_structure
                    potential_structure.append((layer, thickness))
            first_set.add(tuple(potential_structure)) # add this potential_structure to the first_set set

    #print('first_set')
    #for struct in first_set:
    #    print struct

    ## join adjacent repeated materials
    second_set = set() # create new set
    for potential_structure in first_set:
        second_set.add(join_adjacent_repeated_materials(potential_structure))

    ## remove structures where a layer is too thick
    third_set = set()
    for potential_structure in second_set: # check all the structures in the set
        conditions_satisfied=True # default
        for max_condition in maximum_individual_layer_thicknesses: # check this structure using each condition
            for layer in potential_structure: # examine each layer
                if layer[0] == max_condition[0]: # match condition with material
                    if layer[1] > max_condition[1]: # test thickness condition
                        conditions_satisfied=False
        if conditions_satisfied:
            third_set.add(potential_structure)

    ##remove structures that contain too much of a certain material
    fourth_set = set()
    for potential_structure in second_set: # check all the structures in the set
        conditions_satisfied=True # default
        for max_condition in maximum_total_material_thicknesses: # check this structure using each condition
            amount_of_material_in_this_structure = 0 # initialise a counter
            for layer in potential_structure: # examine each layer
                if layer[0] == max_condition[0]: # match condition with material
                    amount_of_material_in_this_structure += layer[1]
                    if amount_of_material_in_this_structure > max_condition[1]: # test thickness condition
                        conditions_satisfied=False
        if conditions_satisfied:
            fourth_set.add(potential_structure)

    return fourth_set

thicknesses = [0,1,2]
materials = ('A', 'B') # Tuple cannot be accidentally appended to later
maximum_number_of_layers = 3
maximum_individual_layer_thicknesses=(('A',30),('B',20))
maximum_total_material_thicknesses=(('A',20),('B',15))

calculate_unique_structure_lengths(thicknesses, materials, maximum_number_of_layers,\
                                   maximum_individual_layer_thicknesses = maximum_individual_layer_thicknesses, \
                                   maximum_total_material_thicknesses = maximum_total_material_thicknesses)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific: what parts of the code are slow and if possible, how can we reproduce the slow behaviour? Also have you tried profiling the code yourself? And if you have, can you provide us with the results.

Comment: Profile your code and see where it's spending most of its time.

Answer (score 2):

```
all_possible_thickness_sets = set(permutations(combinations_with_replacement(thicknesses, maximum_number_of_layers)))
all_possible_layer_material_orders = set(permutations(combinations_with_replacement(materials, maximum_number_of_layers)))
```

Holy crap! These sets are going to be huge! Let's give an example. If `thicknesses` has 6 things in it and `maximum_number_of_layers` is 3, then the first set is going to have about 2 quintillion things in it. Why are you doing this? If these are really the sets you want to use, you're going to need to find an algorithm that doesn't need to build these sets, because it's never going to happen. I suspect these aren't the sets you want; perhaps you wanted [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)?

```
all_possible_thickness_sets = set(product(thicknesses, repeat=maximum_number_of_layers))
```

Here's an example of what `itertools.product` does:

```
>>> for x in product([1, 2, 3], repeat=2):
...     print x
...
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(3, 3)
```

Does that look like what you need?

Answer (score 0):

So one thing you do really often is to add something to a `set`. If you look at the runtime behaviour of sets in the [Python documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), it says, quite on the bottom, about worst cases "Individual actions may take surprisingly long, depending on the history of the container". I think memory reallocation may bite you if you add a lot of elements, because Python has no way of knowing how much memory to reserve when you start.

The more I look at it, the more I think you're reserving more memory than you have to. `third_set` for example doesn't even get used. `second_set` could be replaced by `first_set` if you'd just call `join_adjacent_materials` directly. And if I read it correctly, even `first_set` could go away and you could just create the candidates as you construct `fourth_set`.

Of course the code may become less readable if you put everything into a single bunch of nested loops. However, there are ways to structure your code that don't create unnecessary objects just for readability - you could for example create a function which generates candidates and return each result via `yield`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I instrumented your [code](http://pastebin.com/deGDN7Kd) to enable profiling. Here are the results:

Output:

```
Sun May 25 16:06:31 2014    surprising-challenge-generating-comprehensive-python-list.stats

         348,365,046 function calls in 1,538.413 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time, internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1 1052.933 1052.933 1538.413 1538.413 surprising-challenge-generating-comprehensive-python-list.py:34(calculate_unique_structure_lengths)
 87091200  261.764    0.000  261.764    0.000 {zip}
 87091274  130.492    0.000  130.492    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
174182440   93.223    0.000   93.223    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
       30    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 surprising-challenge-generating-comprehensive-python-list.py:14(join_adjacent_repeated_materials)
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

To get an even finer grained picture of where the code was spending it's time, I used the [line_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler) module on an almost verbatim copy of your code and got the following results for each of your functions:

```
> python "C:\Python27\Scripts\kernprof.py" -l -v surprising-challenge-generating-comprehensive-python-list.py
Wrote profile results to example.py.lprof
Timer unit: 3.2079e-07 s

File: surprising-challenge-generating-comprehensive-python-list.py
Function: join_adjacent_repeated_materials at line 3
Total time: 0.000805183 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     3                                           @profile
     4                                           def join_adjacent_repeated_materials(potential_structure):
     5                                               """
     6                                               Self-explanitory...
     7                                               """
     8                                               #print potential_structure
     9
    10        30          175      5.8      7.0      new_layers = [] # List to hold re-cast structure
    11       100          544      5.4     21.7      for layer in potential_structure:
    12        70          416      5.9     16.6          if len(new_layers) > 0: # if not the first item in the list of layers
    13        41          221      5.4      8.8              last_layer=new_layers[-1] # last element of existing layer list
    14        41          248      6.0      9.9              if layer[0] == last_layer[0]: # true is the two layers are the same material
    15        30          195      6.5      7.8                  combined_layer = (layer[0], layer[1] + last_layer[1])
    16        30          203      6.8      8.1                  new_layers[len(new_layers)-1] = combined_layer
    17                                                       else: # adjcent layers are different material so no comibantion is possible
    18        11           68      6.2      2.7                  new_layers.append(layer)
    19                                                   else: # for the first layer
    20        29          219      7.6      8.7              new_layers.append(layer)
    21
    22        30          221      7.4      8.8      return tuple(new_layers)
```

```
File: surprising-challenge-generating-comprehensive-python-list.py
Function: calculate_unique_structure_lengths at line 24
Total time: 3767.94 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    24                                           @profile
    25                                           def calculate_unique_structure_lengths(thicknesses, materials, maximum_number_of_layers,\
    26                                                                                  maximum_individual_layer_thicknesses, \
    27                                                                                  maximum_total_material_thicknesses):
    28                                               """
    29                                               Create a set on all possible multilayer combinations.
    30
    31                                               thicknesses : if this contains '0' the total number of layers will vary
    32                                                             from 0 to maximum_number_of_layers, otherwise, the
    33                                                             number total number layers will always be maximum_number_of_layers
    34                                                             e.g. arange(0 , 100, 5)
    35
    36                                               materials : list of materials used
    37                                                           e.g. ['Metal', 'Dielectric']
    38
    39                                               maximum_number_of_layers : pretty self-explanitory...
    40                                                                          e.g. 5
    41
    42                                               maximum_individual_layer_thicknesses : filters the created the multilayer structures
    43                                                                                      preventing the inclusion layers that are too thick
    44                                                                                      - this is important after the joining of
    45                                                                                      adjacent materials
    46                                                                                      e.g. (('Metal',30),('Dielectric',20))
    47
    48                                               maximum_total_material_thicknesses : similar to the above but filters structures where the total
    49                                                                                    amount of a particular material is exceeded
    50                                                                                    e.g. (('Metal',50),('Dielectric',100))
    51
    52
    53                                               """
    54                                               # generate all possible thickness combinations and material combinations
    55         1     20305240 20305240.0    0.2      all_possible_thickness_sets = set(permutations(combinations_with_replacement(thicknesses, maximum_number_of_layers)))
    56         1          245    245.0      0.0      all_possible_layer_material_orders = set(permutations(combinations_with_replacement(materials, maximum_number_of_layers)))
    57
    58
    59         1           13     13.0      0.0      first_set = set() # Create set object (list of unique elements, no repeats)

    60        25          235      9.4      0.0      for layer_material_order in all_possible_layer_material_orders:
    61  87091224    896927052     10.3      7.6          for layer_thickness_set in all_possible_thickness_sets:
    62  87091200    920048586     10.6      7.8              potential_structure = [] # list to hold this structure
    63 348364800   4160332176     11.9     35.4              for layer, thickness in zip(layer_material_order[0], layer_thickness_set[0]): # combine the layer thickness with its material
    64 261273600   2334038439      8.9     19.9                  if thickness != 0: # layers of zero thickness are not added to potential_structure
    65 174182400   2003639625     11.5     17.1                      potential_structure.append((layer, thickness))
    66  87091200   1410517427     16.2     12.0              first_set.add(tuple(potential_structure)) # add this potential_structure to the first_set set
    67
    68                                               #print('first_set')
    69                                               #for struct in first_set:
    70                                               #    print struct
    71
    72                                               ## join adjacent repeated materials
    73         1           14     14.0      0.0      second_set = set() # create new set
    74        31          274      8.8      0.0      for potential_structure in first_set:
    75        30         5737    191.2      0.0          second_set.add(join_adjacent_repeated_materials(potential_structure))
    76
    77                                               ## remove structures where a layer is too thick
    78         1           10     10.0      0.0      third_set = set()
    79        23          171      7.4      0.0      for potential_structure in second_set: # check all the structures in the set
    80        22          164      7.5      0.0          conditions_satisfied=True # default
    81        66          472      7.2      0.0          for max_condition in maximum_individual_layer_thicknesses: # check this structure using each condition
    82       104          743      7.1      0.0              for layer in potential_structure: # examine each layer
    83        60          472      7.9      0.0                  if layer[0] == max_condition[0]: # match condition with material
    84        30          239      8.0      0.0                      if layer[1] > max_condition[1]: # test thickness condition
    85                                                                   conditions_satisfied=False
    86        22          149      6.8      0.0          if conditions_satisfied:
    87        22          203      9.2      0.0              third_set.add(potential_structure)
    88
    89                                               ##remove structures that contain too much of a certain material
    90         1           10     10.0      0.0      fourth_set = set()
    91        23          178      7.7      0.0      for potential_structure in second_set: # check all the structures in the set
    92        22          158      7.2      0.0          conditions_satisfied=True # default
    93        66          489      7.4      0.0          for max_condition in maximum_total_material_thicknesses: # check this structure using each condition
    94        44          300      6.8      0.0              amount_of_material_in_this_structure = 0 # initialise a counter
    95       104          850      8.2      0.0              for layer in potential_structure: # examine each layer
    96        60         2961     49.4      0.0                  if layer[0] == max_condition[0]: # match condition with material
    97        30          271      9.0      0.0                      amount_of_material_in_this_structure += layer[1]
    98        30          255      8.5      0.0                      if amount_of_material_in_this_structure > max_condition[1]: # test thickness condition
    99                                                                   conditions_satisfied=False
   100        22          160      7.3      0.0          if conditions_satisfied:
   101        22          259     11.8      0.0              fourth_set.add(potential_structure)
   102
   103         1           16     16.0      0.0      return fourth_set
```

As you can see constructing the`first_set`in`calculate_unique_structure_lengths()`is by far the most time-consuming step.